# Flatten the values list of tuples of a dictonary and multiply the values with the key

Tags: python

I should maintain the order of the list of tuples of my input dict. 
In this input I have the dic I should multiply the key apple with the values of the values. 
The key and val in the tuples should have the same order as dict.
I understand I could convert the list of tuples into a dict but it will have duplicate keys.

How to flatten the list and get me the desired output?

```
dic = {
  "apple":[('key','1'),('val','20'),('key','5'),('val','10')],
  "oranges":[('key','6'),('val','20')],
  "bananas":[('key','11'),('val','120'),('key','15'),('val','101'),('key','22'),('val','101'),('key','45'),('val','101')],
  "gelato":[('key','12'),('val','20'),('key','5'),('val','10')],
}

for key,val in dic.iteritems():
  mystring = key
  new_lis =  [item[1] for item in val if 'key' in item]
  appen =   [mystring + '.'+ s for s in new_lis]
  cool_lis = [item[1] for item in val if 'val' in item]
  print cool_lis
  print appen
```

This  code gives

```
['20', '10']
['gelato.12', 'gelato.5']
['20', '10']
['apple.1', 'apple.5']
['20']
['oranges.6']
['120', '101', '101', '101']
['bananas.11', 'bananas.15', 'bananas.22', 'bananas.45']
```

But I want the output like this

```
output = {
  apple.1: 20,
  apple.5: 10,
  oranges.6:20,
  bananas.11: 120,
  bananas.15: 101,
  bananas.22:101,
  bananas.45: 101,
  gelato.12: 20,
  gelato.5:10

}
```

This is the output dict I wanted to have. Is there any pythonic way of doing it with a single forloop.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
dic = {
    "apple": [('key', '1'), ('val', '20'), ('key', '5'), ('val', '10')],
    "oranges": [('key', '6'), ('val', '20')],
    "bananas": [('key', '11'), ('val', '120'), ('key', '15'), ('val', '101'), ('key', '22'), ('val', '101'),
                ('key', '45'), ('val', '101')],
    "gelato": [('key', '12'), ('val', '20'), ('key', '5'), ('val', '10')],
}


def to_dict(lst):
    filtered = [e for e in lst if e[0] in ('key', 'val')]   
    return {key: value for (_, key), (_, value) in zip(filtered[::2], filtered[1::2])}

result = {}
for key, values in dic.items():
    d = to_dict(values)
    for i, value in d.items():
        result['{}.{}'.format(key, i)] = value

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'gelato.5': '10', 'apple.5': '10', 'bananas.22': '101', 'apple.1': '20', 'oranges.6': '20', 'bananas.15': '101', 'bananas.11': '120', 'bananas.45': '101', 'gelato.12': '20'}
```

I think is better to separate the different steps of your functionality to make it clearer, hence the `to_dict` function.

Comment: rather than list slicing is there a way to get by string pattern from the tuples ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: like if there are many other tuples like [('key','10'),('values','20'),('marketshare','99'),('popularity','1001')]  I need to just extract key,value So I wanted to get the tuples by string

Comment: You could filter first by `'key'` and `'value'` and then apply the above code

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to iterate the inner list in pairs to form key and value for new dictionary giving more flexibility to you in case you want to play around with tuple values

```
dic = {
  "apple":[('key','1'),('val','20'),('key','5'),('val','10')],
  "oranges":[('key','6'),('val','20')],
  "bananas":[('key','11'),('val','120'),('key','15'),('val','101'),('key','22'),('val','101'),('key','45'),('val','101')],
  "gelato":[('key','12'),('val','20'),('key','5'),('val','10')],
}

d={}
for k,v in dic.items():
    for i in range(0,len(v),2):
        d.update({k+'.'+v[i][1]:v[i+1][1]})
print(d)
```

Output

```
{'apple.1': '20',
 'apple.5': '10',
 'bananas.11': '120',
 'bananas.15': '101',
 'bananas.22': '101',
 'bananas.45': '101',
 'gelato.12': '20',
 'gelato.5': '10',
 'oranges.6': '20'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer is it possible to get the tuples by string pattern ? for example my list changes like this [('key','10'),('values','20'),('marketshare','99'),('popularity','1001')] I should be able to get from the string pattern

Comment: You can it sits in the index `0` which I have not included at the moment but you can customize if you follow the above example code. Or else edit the post with an updated requirement.

Comment: @user9538877 what is the expected output for the example list posted in the comments?